# Focus issue on error handling method in CefSharp WPF component

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

we want to reload page when we get an error, so we used this code to handle it, but when this happens cefsharp's ChromiumWebBrowser component loses its focus and when user clicks on an input box cursor does not appear. this situation continues until user uses Alt+Tab to return focus on its containing window again.

```
private void BrowserLoadError(object sender, LoadErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ErrorCode == CefErrorCode.InternetDisconnected)
            e.Browser.Reload();
    }
```

How can we solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried simply calling the `Focus()` method? e.g. `browser.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => browser.Focus()));`

Comment: Yes, it does not work either

Comment: It's very important you list what you've already tried,  wasting my time otherwise.

Comment: Sorry about that, but i just test this codes: `e.Browser.Reload();` `e.Browser.MainFrame.LoadUrl(e.FailedUrl);` `Dispatcher.Invoke(() => browser.Focus() );`

Comment: @amaitland how to remove focus? I have WPF app with two instances of chromium browser control, focus is always there for first instance even though I collapse that browser control. I want to remove focus when I collapse one instance and want to shift focus to active instance.

Comment: @TusharMali Please ask your own question.